# Transforming Dictionary into pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have a program that spits out

```
{'candles': [{'open': 1260.25, 'high': 1260.5, 'low': 1260.0, 'close': 1260.28, 
'volume': 2544, 'datetime': 1556029980000}, {'open': 1260.39, 'high': 1260.61, 
'low': 1260.3501, 'close': 1260.3501, 'volume': 1703, 'datetime': 
1556030040000}, {'open': 1260.35, 'high': 1260.59, 'low': 1260.07, 'close': 
1260.56, 'volume': 2156, 'datetime': 1556030100000}, {'open': 1260.56, 'high': 
1260.56, 'low': 1259.27, 'close': 1259.7, 'volume': 1320, 'datetime': 
1556030160000}, {'open': 1260.06, 'high': 1260.06, 'low': 1259.56, 'close': 
1259.56, 'volume': 800, 'datetime': 1556030220000},
```

I need to insert that into a pandas df with Open High Low Close and volume being each column.

How would I do that with having to manually input it?

Comment: `d` is the output, then `pd.DataFrame(d['candles'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary just has 1 key with all of the records in it, you can just do:

```
data = {'candles': [
            {'close': 1260.28, 'datetime': 1556029980000, 'high': 1260.5, 'low': 1260.0, 'open': 1260.25, 'volume': 2544},
             {'close': 1260.3501, 'datetime': 1556030040000, 'high': 1260.61, 'low': 1260.3501, 'open': 1260.39, 'volume': 1703},
             {'close': 1260.56, 'datetime': 1556030100000, 'high': 1260.59, 'low': 1260.07, 'open': 1260.35, 'volume': 2156},
             {'close': 1259.7, 'datetime': 1556030160000, 'high': 1260.56, 'low': 1259.27, 'open': 1260.56, 'volume': 1320},
             {'close': 1259.56, 'datetime': 1556030220000, 'high': 1260.06, 'low': 1259.56, 'open': 1260.06, 'volume': 800}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data["candles"])

print(df)
      open     high        low      close  volume       datetime
0  1260.25  1260.50  1260.0000  1260.2800    2544  1556029980000
1  1260.39  1260.61  1260.3501  1260.3501    1703  1556030040000
2  1260.35  1260.59  1260.0700  1260.5600    2156  1556030100000
3  1260.56  1260.56  1259.2700  1259.7000    1320  1556030160000
4  1260.06  1260.06  1259.5600  1259.5600     800  1556030220000
```